# Connection to sql-server databases

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have used SQL management studio to create a database. Which connection string should I use now.
Also the database does not appear in the Server object explorer why?
I have worked in past on Dot Net this but I had never handled the database creation  part myself. Please help. Thanks

My own attempt was:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    string constr = @"Data Source = Diabete; Initial Catalog = Cibi; Integrated Security = TRUE;";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)){
                con.Open(); //here get error (cannot find server or database)
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
                    cmd.CommandText = "";
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    { }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: create a text file anywhere on your hard drive and call it `test.UDL`. Now doubleclick on it and a window should appear that helps you create a connection, complete with a `test connection button` Once the connection is working, open this file in notepad and there you see the connection string you can use

Comment: Is 'Diabete' your Server name ?

Comment: Diabate is the name of database

Comment: I have tried that guido and tested the connection and I get an error

Comment: @user1238784 Then set Initial Catalog = Diabete and Data Source to server name (maybe ".", or ".\SQLEXPRESS" or whatever server name you connect to)

Comment: keep changing values until you get the connection working. Also post the error message in your question

Comment: Diabete should be in `initial catalog`not in `data source`

Comment: If you cannot choose your sql server in the UDL file than `sql server browser`service is not running on the sql server

Comment: @Guido, this worked: string constr = @"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Diabete; Integrated Security = TRUE;";

Comment: @Guido then do I have only sqlexpress running? is this also the reason why I cannot see the databases which i create in sqlexpres in the sql object explorer?

Comment: see my answer maybe it can help you

Comment: I have only LAPTOP-7J47C5JA in the dropdown box of the udt file

Comment: check my answer I mentioned 2 possibilitys why that this can happen and why it is not a problem when the connection string still works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put the database in `initial cataglog`and put the sql server name in `Data Source`

make a file with extension `.UDL`and doubleclick on it, set the properties like in this picture.

If you cannot choose your sql server in the top combobox then the `sql server browser`service is not running on the machine where sql server is installed, or there is a firewall issue.

The sql server browser does not needs to be running to get it working, it only helps choosing the server if you dont know its name.

[image]